# Splitting text file into 2D array

Tags: c#, visual-studio, multidimensional-array, file-io

this is the text file that i want to split into a 2D array

`"YHOO",36.86,21,13873900,37.00
"GOOG",684.11,1114,1821650,686.72
"MSFT",50.54,3993,31910300,50.65
"AAPL",94.40,28201,39817000,94.26`

and this is the code I have implemented to do this but it won't work

```
 String input = File.ReadAllText(@"..\..\Data\stockInfo.txt");

        int i = 0, j = 0;
        string[,] result = new string[3, 5];
        foreach (var row in input.Split('\n'))
        {
            j = 0;
            foreach (var col in row.Trim().Split(','))
            {
                result[i, j] = string.Parse(col.Trim());
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of array was wrong. Also, you don't need to string.Parse, as output of Split is IEnumerable of strings

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
string[,] result = new string[4, 5];
foreach (var row in input.Split('\n'))
{
    j = 0;
    foreach (var col in row.Trim().Split(','))
    {
        result[i, j] = col.Trim();
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jagged array `String[][]` (array of array) is often more flexible than 2D one `String[,]`:

```
  string[][] result = File
    .ReadLines(@"..\..\Data\stockInfo.txt")
    .Select(line => line.Split(','))
    .ToArray();
```

If you insist on *2D array* you have to put less efficient code

```
  string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"..\..\Data\stockInfo.txt");

  string[,] result = null;

  for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; ++i) { 
    string[] items = lines.Split(',');

    if (null == result)
      result = new string[lines.Count, items.Length];

    for (int j = 0; j < items.Length; ++j) 
      result[i, j] = items[j];
  }
```