# Text Area CSV Data Split Into 2D Inside For Loop Once Too Many

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multidimensional-array

*Thanks in advance*

7 lines of text data, each line separated further by "|" character.
Data is pasted into a TextArea html element.
Data fed to a function:

- Split the text into an array of lines.
- Take each line and split by pipe character.
- Load into inner array
- Take next item in outer array and repeat.

All the below works except that the inner loop runs one more time than 7.
This causes an undefined error when it hits

`row = allTextLines[i].split('|');`

I've pasted the data from note pad.
I've entered similar data directly into the text area.

Thoughts?

`<textarea id="myTextAreaBox" name="myTextAreaBox"></textarea> <input type="button" value="Get Text" onclick="getText()" />`

```
function getText() {
// Get text
var csv = document.getElementById("myTextAreaBox").value;

// Split by line end
let allTextLines = csv.split(/\r\n|\n|\r/);

// Outer loop
for (let i = 0; allTextLines.length; i++){
let row =[];
row = allTextLines[i].split('|');
let col = [];

// Inner Loop
for (let j = 0; j < row.length; j++){
col.push(row[j]);
  }

 }

}`
```

## Data:

```
BHP.AX|20/07/2022|BUY|250|$9,324.87
BHP.AX|23/08/2022|BUY|230|$9,675.35
BHP.AX|01/09/2022|SELL|280|$10,520.22
BHP.AX|26/09/2022|SELL|100|$5,617.05
BHP.AX|23/06/2023|SELL|100|$5,445.55
BLD.AX|29/10/2018|BUY|100|$5,074.00
BLD.AX|08/11/2019|SELL|100|$6,049.00
```

Trying to end the loading of the data in a 2D array gracefully. While all the data is loaded correctly, the function ends with the error as it attempts one more iteration.

Found this though can't see immediately where may assist: [Splitting text file into 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125249/splitting-text-file-into-2d-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in `for (let i = 0; allTextLines.length; i++){` thus the cycle loops forever. You should fix it to `for (let i = 0; i < allTextLines.length; i++){`.

You could use array methods to make your task in 1 line:

```js
const str = `BHP.AX|20/07/2022|BUY|250|$9,324.87
BHP.AX|23/08/2022|BUY|230|$9,675.35
BHP.AX|01/09/2022|SELL|280|$10,520.22
BHP.AX|26/09/2022|SELL|100|$5,617.05
BHP.AX|23/06/2023|SELL|100|$5,445.55
BLD.AX|29/10/2018|BUY|100|$5,074.00
BLD.AX|08/11/2019|SELL|100|$6,049.00`;

const data = str.split(/\n/).map(row => row.split('|'));

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: That’s a poor error. Thanks for taking the time. And thanks for the one line alternative. Cheers!